# Hadoop file not found exception

Tags: java, hadoop, logging

I am trying my first code to copy files from HDFS to local file system. But, I am unable to copy, even though the files are preset and I am getting the exception: `FileNotFoundExceptoin`.

Here is my code :-

```
public class Exercise1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException ,URISyntaxException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Path glob = new Path("/training/exercises/filesystem/*.txt");
        String localRoot = "/home/hadoop/Training/play_area/exercises/filesystem/e1/";

        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        FileStatus [] files = hdfs.globStatus(glob);
        for (FileStatus file : files ) {
            Path from = file.getPath();
            Path to = new Path(localRoot, file.getPath().getName());
            System.out.println("Copying hdfs file [" + from + "] to local [" + to + "]");
            hdfs.copyToLocalFile(from, to);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is : -

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /training/exercises/filesystem does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatusInternal(FileSystem.java:1488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1421)
    at hdfs.javaAPI.Exercise1.main(Exercise1.java:24)
```

Help me in resolving this error.

Answer (score 2):

As the StackTrace informs you, it is really reading local filesystem (RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus), instead of reading hdfs. This is probably because of a lack of configuration. Try to add the hadoop configuration files as a resource to the object Configuration:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml")); 
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

Comment: core-site.xml alone is enough. No need to add hdfs-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in my machine, no error, no exception, and copy files from hdfs to local successfully. Sorry, I can't help you. Please check your files on hdfs carefully.

Comment: @daivik  Needn't! Perhaps your HDFS does not exist that file indeed!

Answer (score 0):

i've got some error like that, may this will help you, just make a file called log4j.properties. and then, fill the file with this code

```
hadoop.root.logger=DEBUG, console
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
```

please make sure, that this code is corrent in the file

Answer (score -1):

When you start your path with '/' you mean your path starts from the root. You should use the complete URI. Change your path from '/training/exercises/filesystem/*.txt' to '/home/hadoop/training/exercises/filesystem/*.txt'

Comment: @daivik Use your full hdfs url instead. Like this: 'hdfs://yourhostname:yourportnumber/training/exercises/filesystem/.txt'